# A pair of dice is rolled until a sum of either 5 or 7 appears. Find the probability that a 5 occurs first.

Tags: probability

My professor suggested that we first let $E_n$ denote the event that a $5$ occurs on the $n^{\text{th}}$ roll and no $5$ or $7$ occurs on the first $n-1$ rolls, then find $P(E_n)$ and take the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(E_n)$. He calculates $P(E_n)$ like this:

1. The number of ways in which the first $n-1$ rolls will not sum to $5$ or $7$ is $26^{n-1}$
2. The number of ways in which the $n^{\text{th}}$ roll can sum to $5$ is $4$
3. The number of ways you can roll $n$ pairs of dice is $36^n$
4. Therefore, $P(E_n) = \Large\frac{(26^{n-1})(4)}{36^n}$

What I find difficult to understand is that this method seems to be answering a different question altogether, namely:

> A pair of dice is rolled $n$ times. Find the probability that a $5$ occurs on the last roll, and neither a $5$ nor a $7$ is rolled on the first $n-1$ rolls.

I agree that my professor's method for finding $P(E_n)$ works for this altered question because the sample space is the set of all sequences of dice pairs of length $n$. But for the original problem, isn't the sample space the set of all sequences of dice pairs that end with $5$ or $7$ while the rest of the terms are neither $5$ nor $7$? If so, the sample space would be infinite, so we could not simply divide by $36^n$ like we did in step $4$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that there is one more step mentioned in your first paragraph that you have not listed as a numbered step, namely that you have to find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(E_n)$; that will extend the solution to the set of all such sequences.

Comment: @A.J. I agree that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(E_n)$ will give me the correct final solution, what I'm struggling to understand is how we evaluate $P(E_n)$ itself; step 4 doesn't look correct to me. $(26^{n-1})(4)$ is surely the number of ways we can roll $n-1$ times without a 5 or 7, followed by rolling a 5, but why are we dividing by $36^n$? I'm under the impression that we are calculating $P(E_n) = \Large\frac{|E_n|}{|S|}$ where $S$ is our sample space, but isn't $S$ an infinite collection of sequences? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, no, when calculating $P(E_n)$, the sample space is only the sequences of length $n$; we can't include shorter sequences as for $E_n$ to occur no 5 or 7 can appear on the first $n-1$ rolls, nor can we include longer sequences because we stop rolling the dice once a 5 appears on the $n$th roll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **A.J.** has commented, a final step of summing to infinity is missing.

If you carry out that step, you will arrive at an answer of $0.4$

However, you can avoid such a summation by using the method below:

Since a sum of $7$ is effectively barred by stipulating that a sum of $5$ must occur first,

Let $P$ be the **ultimate** probabilty that we get a sum of $5$, then either we get $5$ or are back to start without rolling either $5$ or $7$

Thus$\;\Large P = \frac4{36} + \frac{26}{36}P  \Longrightarrow P= 0.4$

Answer (score 1):

(1) You can try out the suggestions given by your Professor or user AJ or user "true blue anil"

You have to consider all Attempts , from "Attempt $1$" all the way to "Attempt $\infty$" , to evaluate the Probabilities.

(2) Alternatively , my approach is a little more intuitive , without worrying about "Attempt $\infty$" :

In some Attempt $N$ , when we roll the Dice :
Either (A) we might get something other than "{ 5 , 7 }" , which will not change the outcome , but the Experiment/trial continues
Or (B) we get "{ 5 , 7 }" when the Experiment/trial terminates.

When (A) occurs , nothing to calculate.

When (B) occurs :
5 can occur via $1+4$ , $2+3$ , $3+2$ , $4+1$ (4 events).
7 can occur via $1+6$ , $2+5$ , $3+4$ , $4+3$ , $5+2$ , $6+1$ (6 events).

Hence Probability that 5 occurs first is $4/(4+6)=0.4$
Probability that 7 occurs first is $6/(4+6)=0.6$